# best divisor for a set of integers that minimizes sum of remainders

Tags: discrete-mathematics

suppose  I have a list of integers such as:
$23,145,189,893,670,34,4574,1987,103,764,2045,141$
what is the one divisor for all that would minimize the sum of all remainders?
So if i choose $45$ as divisor for the above list the remainders would accordingly be:
$23,10,9,38,40,34,29,7,13,44,20,6$ giving us a sum of remainders of $273$. What divisor would give us a lower such sum: or better the lowest such sum?

I believe the question can be formally restated as:
$y=\sum_{i=0}^n(log(d)+log(i_n\renewcommand*{\bmod}{\mathbin{\%}}\, d))$
where $d$ is the divisor and $ i_1,i_2,i_3,...,i_n $ is the given the sequence of integers and we want the divisor that minimizes function $y$. Symbol 
$ i_n\renewcommand*{\bmod}{\mathbin{\%}}\, d \,$ is the remainder for each $i_n$. The logarithm can be at any base.

Comment: $ { } {1} { } $.

Comment: As implied by Henning Makholm's comment, you need to specify a tradeoff between the size of the divisor and the size of the sum of the remainders.  If the list were $16,18$ you could divide by $2$ with no remainder, but you could also divide by $16$ with remainders of $0,2$ and sum $2$.  It seems the second is what you want, but the sum of remainders is higher.

Comment: OK . If we set  d=size of divisor+size of remainder (divisor is the same for all integers in the list) the sum of all d's must be at minimum